# Testing the average running time of binary search

Tags: c, arrays, search, binary

How can I test the running time of binary search given an already sorted array of n unique elements ? Specifically what's the position of the key I'm searching for going to be that will lead to the average running time ? For example when I tested the average time of linear search I created an array of random unique elements,also the elements are >-1, and put the number -1 in the middle of the array and then I searched for it using a linear search function I implemented.

Answer (score 0):

1) Start time count 
2) Pick a random number from the array 
3) Run your search algorithm 
4) Repeat from step (2) N (N=zillion) times 
5) Stop time count 
6) Divide time count by N
Profit.

Comment: I can't understand how you relate average case of binary search with the key we are searching for being random or not. Isn't all this about they key's position in the array similar to the linear search example I mentioned. I expected something similar with saying that the best case for the key is to be in the middle and according to that what will be the key's position to lead to the average case of binary search.

Comment: Do you want to *test* or to *calculate*? If former - the way is outlined in the answer. If latter - you can do it with pen-and-paper - sum up the running times for each index and divide by their number. Totally analytically.

Comment: You see I have counted the average time of linear search already using the clock() function in c putting the key in the middle of the array(average case of linear search) and then searching for it and made my conclusions for array sizes varying from 100million ints to 1billion ints via 100 million increments. I basically want to do the same for binary search and all I wonder is where should the key be located for its average case.